# Launchd not loading nginx on startup

Tags: nginx, plist, homebrew, launchd

I installed NGINX with homebrew then I got info and followed the instructions to load the launchd plist

```
$ brew info nginx
nginx: stable 1.6.2, devel 1.7.7, HEAD
...
To load nginx:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    nginx
```

The problem is nginx doesn't load when I restart.

The plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.nginx</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx</string>
        <string>-g</string>
        <string>daemon off;</string>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/opt/nginx/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

> The trick to this is that Mac OSX won’t let anything other than “root”
>   or “system” level services use a port number below 1024.

Read more here: http://derickbailey.com/2014/12/27/how-to-start-nginx-on-port-80-at-mac-osx-boot-up-log-in/

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your question because I was having the same issue. Three things helped me make it work:

- change ownership of plist file to `root:wheel` (`sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/opt/nginx/*.plist`)
- create the symlink in `/Library/LaunchAgents` instead of `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, because you probably run nginx on port 80, which requires root privileges.
- Remove the `<string>-g</string>` and `<string>daemon off;</string>` lines from the plist (before loading it with `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist`)

I'm not sure *why* those two lines are invalid, but I found out by trying to execute the `/usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx` with `-g daemon off;` added to it, it also failed.